# Load more results like on facebook/twitter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Maybe you've seen on Facebook/Twitter this effect. I want to load more results and append them to the existent ones. No problem so far. How can I keep track of how many results I have yet, to know from where on to query next time?

I have a number of answers:

1. Wrap the results into a div with an id, results1, results 2 ...and then get the last id and multiply it by how many results are in a container
2. Keep the number in a variable, reset it every time the list is requested after you come from another page.

Comment: I would just keep it in a global javascript variable.  What do you mean by "reset it every time the list is requested after you come from another page."

Comment: As you say, keep it in a global variable. When you start to load results you have to restart that variable, to start from the beginning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at this.

It worked fine for me.

http://youhack.me/2010/05/14/an-alternative-to-pagination-facebook-and-twitter-style/

I'm just posting a link rather than an answer, because you can go through the code and will be able to solve the problem by yourself.

Comment: Perfect! this was exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I've tried the demo. It totally resets the page after I pressed F5. How to keep track what loaded?

Comment: @hanuman0503 either use a cookie, session or append ?id=10 to the url.  When you refresh the page, you'll need to load in results from a specific id.  If you don't know what mean, I'd ask a new question.  This is pretty simple stuff.

Comment: I found this helpul http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/create-a-twitter-like-load-more-widget/